# Tableview doesn't populate JavaFX

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, empty-list

so i have seen all the already asked questions, and tried them, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public class SelectClientInterface implements Initializable {

//Views
@FXML
TableView<String> selectClientTable;
@FXML
TableColumn<String, String> CodeC, NomC, RegCommerceC, IdFiscalC, NArtFisC;
@FXML
Button selectClientButton, returnSelectClientButton;

ObservableList<Clients> mylist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    populateTable();
}


void populateTable() {
    mylist.addAll(clientsArray);

    for (Clients client : clientsArray) {
        CodeC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(client.getCodeC())));
        NomC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(client.getNomC()));
        RegCommerceC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(client.getRegCom()));
        IdFiscalC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(client.getIdFiscal()));
        NArtFisC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(client.getnArticleFiscal()));

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(client.getCodeC()) + client.getNomC() + client.getRegCom() + client.getIdFiscal() + client.getnArticleFiscal());
    }

}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14YY1.png)

Comment: Where is `clientsArray` declared ?

Comment: is it declared and filled in the previous screen, and as you can see i tested with the log and found it filled and works and shows items well

Comment: how could i do that? i'm new to javaFX...

Comment: use the `getCellFactory()`

Comment: i did it just like this: System.out.println(CodeC.getCellValueFactory().toString()); at the end of populate table void, and here is what it printed:
interfaces.controllers.SelectClientInterface$$Lambda$320/1113190516@21db2d8f

Comment: Do you have a `selectClientTable.setItems(mylist);` somewhere?

Comment: nope, i don't have that at all...

Comment: i just added that at the end of the populateTable void, and it worked, can you please explain to me a little bit?

Comment: Well, the table needs to know what items it should display, and if you don't make the connection between the items and the table, it has no way of knowing what items it should display.

Comment: now i'm having a problem, so the list contains 2 items, so i should have 2 rows having an item respectively, but now my table has 2 rows with the same item, which is the second one (last in list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong type parameters for `TableColumn` and `TableView`. Since the items of the `TableView` are of type `Client` (at least that seems to be the intention), you should use `TableView<Client>` and `TableColumn<Client, String>`.

Furthermore you're not setting the `TableView` items.

Also you're using `TableColumn.cellValueFactory` wrong. The `cellValueFactory` is used for every row that `TableView` displays on screen. Using values of the last `Client` results in the values from the last item being used for every non-empty row. Instead you should use the values provided by the `TableColumn.CellDataFeatures` passed to the `Callback`.

```
@FXML
TableView<Client> selectClientTable;
@FXML
TableColumn<Client, String> CodeC, NomC, RegCommerceC, IdFiscalC, NArtFisC;
@FXML
Button selectClientButton, returnSelectClientButton;

ObservableList<Clients> mylist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    populateTable();
}


void populateTable() {
    mylist.addAll(clientsArray);

    CodeC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(c.getValue().getCodeC())));
    NomC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getNomC()));
    RegCommerceC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getRegCom()));
    IdFiscalC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getIdFiscal()));
    NArtFisC.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getnArticleFiscal()));

    for (Clients client : clientsArray) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(client.getCodeC()) + client.getNomC() + client.getRegCom() + client.getIdFiscal() + client.getnArticleFiscal());
    }

    selectClientTable.setItems(mylist);
}
```